# Check similarity between strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I am working with data in a table (using pandas, of course). I am facing the following problem: I want to associate some products with a label. For example, "hot pepper shaker 100g" or "diet coke 2L". However, some of the items are out of the standard, for example, instead of "diet coke 2L" its called "2 litter bottle coke diet". I would like to use a function to read the string "2 litter bottle coke diet", check through a list of standard labels and classify the string with the correct standard label. I tried using the function SequenceMatcher from the difflib, but it hits only 3/4 of the total products I have. Is there a better "pythonic" solution?

Comment: You don't even tell us if the example you presented to matched correctly. This is very little information to go on.

Comment: @MadPhysicist while I completely agree with you that I should have given this info, I don't think it was a reason for downvoting since I have shown research effort, the question was still clear and it is useful (at least for me). Thank you anyway, I will not make this mistake in future questions. And I added a solution that worked for me, in case you are interested in this problem too.

Comment: @donut don't forget that you possess domain knowledge that we do not.  If you want a helpful answer without us making guesses you need to give as much information as possible.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue here will not be about languages but about string distance measures and tokens. For example, if the label reads “Diet Coke 2L”, do you match it to a one token string “Coke” or a  two token string “Diet Coke”? Assuming that you’ve already determined the number of tokens you want to match on, I’d suggest using the jellyfish library and play with distance measures such as Levenshtein Distance.

As for a code example:

```
from jellyfish import levenshtein_distance

label=“Diet Coke 2 Liter”
match_labels=[“Sprite”,”Coke”,”Pepsi”]

# Split string into length one tokens
label_split=label.split()

#Tolerance for matches
match_tol=1 #Match if at most one letter is different

# Loop through each word, if match then break
match_tuple=[]
for word in label_split:
  for match in match_labels:
    if levenshtein_distance(word,match)<=match_tol:
      match_tuple.append((match_labels,word,match))
      break
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but in my case it didn't help. I added a solution if you are interested in this problem too.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the best solution I have found is with this small machine learning

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import euclidean_distances

corpus = [x,y,z,w] #x is the string we are trying to classify as one of the labels y,z or w.

vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
features = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus).todense()

for f in features:
    print(euclidean_distances(features[0],f))
```

Then we select the smaller distance and get the best label. For my problem, the hit-rate was close to 100% for a list of 8256 strings.